# How to hide/show the UIimageview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(250, 100, 30, 30);
    as = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
    as.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"check" ofType:@"png"]];
    [as setImage:img];
    [self.view addSubview:as];
    BOOL test= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switch"];
    NSLog(@"%@", (test ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
    if(test == YES)
        {
            as.hidden=NO;
        }
    else
        {
            as.hidden=YES;
        }
}
```

The `test` results `YES`  but the `imageView` doesn't listen the command `.hidden` or update every time when the `viewDidAppear`.If it is not when I restart the app and it disappear after I turn it to yes I show perfectly but after than I never goes always there I can't make it hidden.
any idea why it is not reacting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is you create new `UIImageView` every time when your view appears. You have to create `UIImageView` as once:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(250, 100, 30, 30);
    as = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
    as.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"check" ofType:@"png"]];
    as.image = img;
    [self.view addSubview:as];
    [as release];
}
```

and then show/hide it in -`viewDidAppear` method:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    BOOL test = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switch"];
    NSLog(@"%@", (test ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
    if(test == YES) {
        as.hidden = NO;
    }
    else {
        as.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```