# Hiding a UIImageView in Cocoa Touch

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimageview

I want to toggle displaying an image in my program.  Here is my code simplified:

```
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
UIImageView *selector = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: newImage];
[selector setFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 0, 64, 64)];
[overView addSubview: selector];
[overView bringSubviewToFront: selector];
selector.hidden = TRUE;

[newImage release]
```

Later in the code:

```
-(IBAction)Button1Click
{
  selector.hidden = FALSE;
}

-(IBAction)Button2Click
{
  selector.hidden = TRUE;
}
```

Later still:

```
[selector release];
```

When I run and click the two buttons the "selector" image never shows up.  If I debug the program I can see the program reaches the lines under the IBActions, but it has no effect.  Here is the strange thing:  If I set the line early on to:

```
selector.hidden = FALSE;
```

Then I can see the "selected" image the whole time and it never turns off no matter what button I press.  Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
I know it was unclear in the code but "selector" is in the same scope in all the code.  Adding "self." to "selector" fixed the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334624/uiimageview-hidden-no-but-image-is-not-visible

Comment: Not sure if any of this is related to your problem, but you shouldn't release the image that is returned from `imageNamed:` (it's already autoreleased). You also typically use `YES` and `NO` instead of `TRUE` and `FALSE` in Objective-C. `bringSubviewToFront:` is unnecessary after using `addSubview:`, because it adds it as the topmost subview anyway.

Comment: it's unclear with the code provided if `selector` is actually in scope and what it's actually referring to at different points

Comment: Don't update the title to say SOLVED - you've accepted an answer, that is visible to everyone. (Well done!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your code snippets it seems that you have property "selector" (accessed in IBActions) and local variable "selector" used in "main" snippet.  If this is the case, you have to do something like this:

```
self.selector = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: newImage];
```

instead of

```
UIImageView *selector = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: newImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case in method 'Button1Click' (and the other one) 'selector' is unknown, cause it was declared locally here: `UIImageView *selector = ...`.

You need proper reference to it, accessible from your button click methods. You can declare it in your *.h file, then use it anywhere in your class, then release it at end (in dealloc method).

And of course you shouldn't release this UIImage. Please read Apple documentation about memory management. It will be really hard to go further without it :)

Andrei's answer is right I think, but little too short for someone fresh.

Comment: This is probably it. I suspect that the questioner is ignoring a warning that he has declared an instance variable named `selector` (without it, the actions would fail to compile) and a local variable named `selector` (as shown in the first code snippet in the question), in which case the latter shadows (blocks its scope's access to) the former. Either that or the first code snippet is in a different class from the actions, in which case they're separate variables with no relation to each other.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to declare instance variables in the header file, and I recommend not doing so. Declare them in the `@implementation` in the class's own .m file. There's no reason why any other class should ever see them.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView *selector = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: newImage];`

looks like it's "shadowing" your selector ivar.  Look at your @interface and see if selector is also in the ivar list.  If so, then just remove the **UIImageView *** portion.

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing for more information about that.  You can also turn on a warning flag in Xcode that will warn you when it encounters one. Surprisingly it's not on by default.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
UIImageView *selector = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: newImage] autorelease];
```